# WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.Current.Post executes lambda on background thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

When posting a lambda expression to the current `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext`, I find that the lambda code executes on a background thread:

```
// running on main thread here

myLabel = new Label();
this.Controls.Add(myLabel);

WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.Current.Post( ignore => {

    // returns true !
    bool invokeRequired = myLabel.InvokeRequired; 

    // returns a background thread, not the UI thread
    int threadId = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId; 

    // throws, because we are (unexpectedly) on a background, different thread
    myLabel.Text = "whatever";

},null);
```

Besides, `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.Current` does not seem to return a `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext`, but rather an ordinary `System.Threading.SynchronizationContext`.

This is suddenly happening on a form that used to have no thread problems and hasn't been recently modified (other parts of the solution were). I have tried looking for obvious mistakes (such as, code that instantiates the form itself on a background thread, or controls created on a background thread) but I haven't been able to find significant violations.

Perhaps I am looking in the wrong direction?

Comment: `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.Current` will return null when queried from another thread, you have to save it for later use

Comment: It is not null; it is null when cast. I'll clarify, thank you @Sriram.

Comment: It will be null, pls do clarify

Comment: @SriramSakthivel It's pretty clear: the delegate supplied to `Post` is actually invoked, therefore there is a `SynchronizationContext`. The problem is that accessing the UI from that delegate fails, because somehow it's not running on the UI thread.

Comment: @magma What does `SynchronizationContext.Current.GetType()` give you in the debugger?

Comment: @shambulator check my answer this also may happen

Comment: @shambulator the type is System.Threading.SynchronizationContext

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.Current` is the same as `SynchronizationContext.Current`. You should be getting a compiler warning that you are invoking a base static member through a derived class.

Check `SynchronizationContext.Current.GetType()` and you'll find out that you are running under a different sync context.

Capture the correct context on the UI thread and store it.

Comment: Does the compiler warns if you use `Base class static member` through Derived?

Comment: @usr indeed, and creating a `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext context = new WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext();` allowed the Post to run as expected. Now I know where to look, thank you.

Comment: It turns out that another developer had submitted a rogue SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext call in a different WinForm. Again, thank you for your help.